# Change date format and keep chronological order in graph in R

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, format, chronological

I'm trying to change my column "Week" to the date format %d/%m/%Y. I first convert the column type to date by doing mutate `(Week = as.Date(Week))` and then I do `mutate(Week = format(as.Date(Week), "d%/%m/%Y"))` which does the job, however when I plot it as a graph I can't have the dates in chronological order because the column Week has become of type character.

Is there any way I can get my dates to be %d/%m/%Y and be plotted in chronological order?

Thanks :)

Comment: don't convert week to a character. ggplot will work with the dates directly. Use scales_x_date(date_labels= ...) to fix the formatting

Comment: thanks. I get my graph x ordered by day and month and not chronologically if I use this

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you parse the date character to a date object using your format. Then, ggplot recognizes this and puts the right labels to the x axis:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <-
  tibble(Date = c("30/11/2020", "01/12/2020")) %>%
  mutate(Date = Date %>% parse_date(format = "%d/%m/%Y"))
data
#> # A tibble: 2 x 1
#>   Date      
#>   <date>    
#> 1 2020-11-30
#> 2 2020-12-01

qplot(x = Date, y = 1, data = data)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your help. In the graph I get the format %B d% but I was looking for %d/%m/%Y?

Comment: You can `qplot(x = Date, y = 1, data = data) + scale_x_date(date_labels = "%d/%m/%Y")` to adjust date format in the plot. The year was omitted because it is the same in all rows of my example.

Comment: That finally worked! I added date_breaks so that all weeks were included and now it is in the correct format, thanks a lot, it is highly appreciated